# SpringData and Elasticsearch - java.lang.StackOverflowError while using ignoreFields

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using simple relationship (spring data elasticsearch) but springboot is throwing StackOverflowError

```
@Document(indexName = "users", type = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type= FieldType.Nested,ignoreFields={"users"})
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();
}

@Document(indexName = "groups", type = "group")
public class Group {

    @Id
    String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, ignoreFields ={"groups"})
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}

public interface UserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, String>{

}

public interface GroupRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Group, String> {

}
```

Any Idea what is problem?

Code is from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/entities

Thanks
Rajan

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

As you said: spring-boot is throwing StackOverflowError.

It's because of no safeguards or detecting circular dependencies in spring-boot.

Look at spring-boot source: [MappingBuilder.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4c7dd4939a9d7e8bb03d14d14225494b58fcc91e/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/MappingBuilder.java#L137), there's loop that will never break when you have class A that have a `@Field` annotation referencing class B, that have `@Field` annotation referencing class A.